# UITableViewController resizing TableView sporadically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a few `UITableViewControllers` in my app. I have `UITextFields` in some of the `UITableViewCells`. Sometimes the `tableView` resizes itself when the keyboard appears, but not always.

I've attached a couple examples. Both have a `UITextField` that are the current `firstResponder`. I've dragged up for both screen shots to show the scroll indicator.

The `UITableViewController` on the left resized it's `tableView` when the keyboard appeared, but the `UITableViewController` on the right did not. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks to everyone for helping me on this problem. Still hasn't been solved. They both have a `UINavigationController` as their `parentViewController`. The one on the right is the `UINavigationControllers` `topViewController` while the one on the left was presented from the `topViewController`. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are they really both `UITableViewController` or is one just a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Thats a tricky one, I have seen that before in one of my apps and believe it had to do with how the UITableView was added. Could it be that the one on the left is added straight as a `UITableViewController` in an `UINavigationController` but the on the right is added as a subview (`UITableView`) or not in an `UINavigationController`?

Comment: i also got that problem maybe you have included some Outlets in the table view not in the tableviewcell

Comment: Both use/implement the `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: Weird. A *workaround* would be to set a `tag` to the `UITextField` and when the delegate responds fetch the indexPath using the `tag` and then use the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @PaulPeelen - Didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you set any `contentInset` or `contentOffset` for the `UITableView` in either of them? Could be that what screwing things up.

Answer (score 2):

So, I've figured out a workaround:

```
- (void)setContentInsetWithTextField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = 216;

    CGFloat movement = (textField.isFirstResponder ? keyboardHeight : -keyboardHeight);

    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.tableView.contentInset;
    contentInset.bottom = contentInset.bottom + movement;
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInset;
}
```

Call this method in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and the `textFieldDidEndEditing` and it solves the problem!